# Pandas counting the number of group elements excluding the focal element

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame looks like this

```
company   tool   category         year  month
Amazon    A      productivity     2014     9
Amazon    B      productivity     2014     8
Apple     A      productivity     2014     6
Apple     C      CRM              2015     4 
Apple     D      CRM              2015     3
Google    C      CRM              2015     6
Google    E      HR               2014     9 
Google    F      productivity     2014     11
Google    G      productivity     2014     12
```

The first column shows the purchaser of the tool, tool column corresponds to the name of the tool, category shows a tool's purpose, year and month are the dates of purchase.

For each tool, I would like to create a following data:

```
tool   monthlydate    cumulative_sales no_companies_comp year month
A      2014/06              1                 0          2014  6
A      2014/07              1                 0          2014  7
A      2014/08              1                 1          2014  8
A      2014/09              2                 1          2014  9
A      2014/10              2                 1          2014  10
A      2014/11              2                 2          2014  11
A      2014/12              2                 2          2014  12
```

where cumulative_sales corresponds to the cumulative sales of the tool at hand in a given year month, no_companies_comp corresponds to the cumulative number of companies that purchased a competitor tool in a given year month (note that a company might purchase multiple competitor tools, but we will only count its first purchase as we are interested in number of companies). How could I achieve this?

Comment: Is `competitors_cum_sales` missing from your example output? Or does that refer to the column `no_companies_comp`?

Comment: oh it refers to the no_companies_comp, let me fix

Answer (score 4):

With a simple groupby we can obtain the number of sales and companies buying each tool:

```
>>> sales = df.groupby(['tool', 'year', 'month']).size()
>>> sales
tool  year  month
A     2014  6        1
            9        1
B     2014  8        1
C     2015  4        1
            6        1
D     2015  3        1
E     2014  9        1
F     2014  11       1
G     2014  12       1
dtype: int64
>>> companies = df.groupby(['tool', 'year', 'month'])['company'].nunique()
>>> companies
tool  year  month
A     2014  6        1
            9        1
B     2014  8        1
C     2015  4        1
            6        1
D     2015  3        1
E     2014  9        1
F     2014  11       1
G     2014  12       1
Name: company, dtype: int64
```

Then cumulative sales is easy:

```
>>> sales.groupby('tool').cumsum()
tool  year  month
A     2014  6        1
            9        2
B     2014  8        1
C     2015  4        1
            6        2
D     2015  3        1
E     2014  9        1
F     2014  11       1
G     2014  12       1
dtype: int64
```

Note that a number of months are missing, so we should reindex:

```
>>> dates = [(2014 + n // 12, (n - 1) % 12 + 1) for n in range(6, 19)]
>>> idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
...     (tool, year, month) for tool in df['tool'].unique() for year, month in dates
... ], names=['tool', 'year', 'month'])
>>> cum_sales = sales.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).groupby('tool').cumsum()
>>> cum_sales.unstack('tool')
tool        A  B  C  D  E  F  G
year month                     
2014 6      1  0  0  0  0  0  0
     7      1  0  0  0  0  0  0
     8      1  1  0  0  0  0  0
     9      2  1  0  0  1  0  0
     10     2  1  0  0  1  0  0
     11     2  1  0  0  1  1  0
2015 1      2  1  0  0  1  1  0
     2      2  1  0  0  1  1  0
     3      2  1  0  1  1  1  0
     4      2  1  1  1  1  1  0
     5      2  1  1  1  1  1  0
     6      2  1  2  1  1  1  0
     12     2  1  0  0  1  1  0
```

You can of course change the range of dates as needed.

Number of companies buying a competitor tool is the number of companies buying any tool, minus the number of companies buying each tool. We can do that with `transform` but similarly to above, we need to reindex first:

```
>>> companies = companies.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
>>> total_companies = companies.groupby(['year', 'month']).transform('sum')
>>> cum_compet_companies = (total_companies - companies).groupby('tool').cumsum()
>>> cum_compet_companies.unstack('tool')
tool        A  B  C  D  E  F  G
year month                     
2014 6      0  1  1  1  1  1  1
     7      0  1  1  1  1  1  1
     8      1  1  2  2  2  2  2
     9      2  3  4  4  3  4  4
     10     2  3  4  4  3  4  4
     11     3  4  5  5  4  4  5
2015 1      3  4  5  5  4  4  5
     2      3  4  5  5  4  4  5
     3      4  5  6  5  5  5  6
     4      5  6  6  6  6  6  7
     5      5  6  6  6  6  6  7
     6      6  7  6  7  7  7  8
     12     3  4  5  5  4  4  5
```

The rest is just simply joining the data and adding `monthlydate`, possibly playing with indexes:

```
>>> res = cum_sales.to_frame('cumulative_sales').join(
...     cum_compet_companies.to_frame('no_companies_comp')
... ).reset_index()
>>> res['monthlydate'] = res['year'].combine(res['month'], lambda y, m: f'{y}/{m:02}')
>>> res.set_index(['tool', 'monthlydate']).loc['A']  # just tool A
             year  month  cumulative_sales  no_companies_comp
monthlydate                                                  
2014/06      2014      6                 1                  0
2014/07      2014      7                 1                  0
2014/08      2014      8                 1                  1
2014/09      2014      9                 2                  2
2014/10      2014     10                 2                  2
2014/11      2014     11                 2                  3
2015/12      2015     12                 2                  3
2015/01      2015      1                 2                  3
2015/02      2015      2                 2                  3
2015/03      2015      3                 2                  4
2015/04      2015      4                 2                  5
2015/05      2015      5                 2                  5
2015/06      2015      6                 2                  6
>>> res.set_index(['tool', 'monthlydate'])  # all tools
                  year  month  cumulative_sales  no_companies_comp
tool monthlydate                                                  
A    2014/06      2014      6                 1                  0
     2014/07      2014      7                 1                  0
     2014/08      2014      8                 1                  1
     2014/09      2014      9                 2                  2
     2014/10      2014     10                 2                  2
...                ...    ...               ...                ...
G    2015/02      2015      2                 0                  5
     2015/03      2015      3                 0                  6
     2015/04      2015      4                 0                  7
     2015/05      2015      5                 0                  7
     2015/06      2015      6                 0                  8

[91 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Let me try to apply it form my data, will let you know

Comment: I tried, there is an issue which is no_companies_comp corresponds to the number of tools companies purchased, not the number of companies that purchased a competitor tool

Comment: Also in the original dataset, observations might start from earlier dates, idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(tool, 2014 + n // 12, (n - 1) % 12 + 1) for tool in df['tool'].unique() for n in range(6, 19)], names=['tool', 'year', 'month'])  not likely to work

Comment: Sure @edyvedy13 you should adjust the index to the range of dates you actually use.

Comment: @edyvedy13 you can use min(df.year) in place of 2014 and everything else should be modular